# Get pixels and points for UIView and UIImageView on Swift

Tags: swift, uiview

I have an ViewController with a View called MasterView(it's the first UIView of the ViewController)

Inside the MasterView, I have a UIImageView, both views have a width of 320, take a look on the images below:

[image]

[image]

But when I try to get the image size programmatically, I use the following code:

```
/* imagemPrincipalCabeca is an IBOutlet connected to the UIImageView */
print("master uiview frame: \(view.frame.width)")
print("master uiview bounds: \(view.bounds.width)")
print("subview uiimageview frame: \(imagemPrincipalCabeca.frame.width)")
print("subview uiimageview bounds: \(imagemPrincipalCabeca.bounds.width)")
```

I got the following text on the console:

```
master uiview frame: 375.0
master uiview bounds: 375.0
subview uiimageview frame: 320.0
subview uiimageview bounds: 320.0
```

If the UIView width and the UIImageView on my code is 320. Why the view.frame.width results in 375 ?

I know the device screen in pixels is 375 and device points in screen is 320, but why I got different values when I use the code above?

Comment: What is the device model that you are using to test? Probably one of those iPhone X 375 x 812,
iPhone 8, iPhone 7,  iPhone 6s Plus, iPhone 6 Plus, iPhone 6s and iPhone 6 375 x 667

Comment: And you are using iPhone SE in your canvas layout 320 x 568

Comment: I use the iPhone SE 1st generation model in Xcode and I use the Iphone 8 in iOS Simulator

Comment: So what screen size would you expect? It looks correct for me.

Comment: Where did you put the `print` statements? If you put them in `viewDidLoad`, the image view would not have had enough time to lay out. Try printing the sizes in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: I was using the print statement inside <code>viewDidLoad</code>, I try to using it with <code>viewDidAppear</code> and it didn't work, but when I used with <code>viewDidLayoutSubviews</code> it worked. Thank you so much for your help @Sweeper You saved me. I was working on this code for an entire day and you helped me to find a solution.

Comment: @LeoDabus I was expecting the same width for both views, since both views use the entire width space available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the @SWeeper comment.
I test the `viewDidAppear` method and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.
The `viewDidAppear` method didn't work for me,
but the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method WORKED for me.

I use a `ContainerView`, maybe this is the reason why I need to use the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method to make my code get the correct width of my view.